# Is the flag to disable unsolicited responses working correctly?

Tags: spring-saml

I am using spring-saml 1.0.1 RELEASE. I added the property supportUnsolicitedResponse to my SP extendedMetadata and set the value to false, but this did not prevent unsolicited IDP responses.

Upon inspection of the code in src/main/java/org/springframework/security/saml/websso/WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java line 130 I found that the call to check this flag is for the peer extended metadata...

`context.getPeerExtendedMetadata().isSupportUnsolicitedResponse()`

not the local extended metadata.

This seems incorrect to me. It seems to me that I am configuring my SP to accept or reject unsolicited responses so it should be set in the local extended metadata and the code should be looking there not the peer. Am I missing something? Can someone explain how this is suppose to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have figured this out. The way the supportUnsolicitedResponse is implemented in Spring-SAML is to allow the SP to individually specify for each IDP whether they can send an IDP-initiated SAML response. This gives the SP flexibility to allow some IDPs to send IDP-initiated SAML responses, and not allow others. There is not a way for the SP to specify that it will not accept IDP-initiated responses from any IDP.

This behavior for the property supportUnsolicitedResponse is documented in Table 7.2 in the spring-SAML documentation at http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html.